# wordpress metaWeblog.newPost xmlrpc create category if not exist, and prevent duplicate titles from codeigniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I'm using codeigniter to post to my wordpress blog.

**code**

model

```
function doPost($title='new post',$content='hi',$categories=array('new'),$keys='new, none')
    {
        $this->load->library('xmlrpc');

        $thePost= array(
            array(
                'title' => array($title,'string'),
                'date_created_gmt'=>array($datetime,'dateTime.iso8601'),
                'description' => array($content,'string'),
                'categories' => array($categories,'struct'),
                'mt_keywords'    => array($keys,'string'),
                'post_type' => array('post','string'),
            ),
            'struct'
        );
        $this->xmlrpc->server('http://demo.com/xmlrpc.php', 80);
        $this->xmlrpc->method('metaWeblog.newPost');
        $request = array('1',$user,$pass,$thePost,TRUE);
        $this->xmlrpc->request($request);
        $result = $this->xmlrpc->send_request();

        if (!$result) {
            echo $this->xmlrpc->display_error();
        } else {
            print_r($this->xmlrpc->display_response());
        }
    }
```

but i have a question.

**1st.** can i check if there a post already exist with same title ?

**2nd.** currently if i post a category that is not there, post is submited as uncategorised,
how can i alter this to create category if not exists ??

**3rd.** Can i post multiple posts in one xmlrpc request ?

thanks, i'm using latest version of wordpress (today is day0 for me with wordpress !) and its located on remote server..

thanks thanks

Answer (score 2):

*Re- 1st / 2nd.*

You can use [`wp.getTerms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Taxonomies#wp.getTerms) to check if category exists.

Add the category using [`wp.newTerm`](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Taxonomies#wp.newTerm)

Create a post using [`wp.newPost`](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost)

*Re- 3rd.*

> Can I post multiple posts in one xmlrpc request ?

No, not to push in content.

Nonetheless if you do have access to the WP installation you can create a small plugin that would pull content from a feed and `insert_posts` after a remote trigger from your CI application.

Comment: can you explain how can we use this wp.newTerm in php ?